# How to export all raw data from Firebase Analytics

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

We have an app with many analytics logs. We'd like to export the raw events and their parameters. Some events have a lot of parameters which are not reasonable to setup as "custom dimension". Hence, we'd rather export the data and analyze ourselves. A .csv file would be great. Can it be done?

Answer (score 3):

You can get raw data by exporting it to Google BigQuery

Here is how to link FireBase to Google BigQuery:

```
1. Sign in to Firebase.
2. Click the Settings icon, then select Project Settings.
3. On the Project Settings page, click the Integrations tab.
4. On the BigQuery card, click Link.
```

https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6318765?hl=en#zippy=%2Cin-this-article

Your data will be presented in BigQuery as tables and you can query them using SQL. You can save your data to csv (or other formats) by using the SAVE RESULTS button in BigQuery console as well.